# JS app auto-refreshing/ element disappearing EDITED

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

**EDITED**

Managed to get most of it working, but have a problem towards the end.

I have an html file with a few input fields and div elements to which I have to append a recipe when it is created.

So I have two classes separated in modules - recipe and book, and an app.js file which should then combine the both into a working app.

The problem I am now having is that whenever i click the Add button the recipe shows only for a millisecond and then disappears.. I have no clue why. Could it be because my classes are self-invoking? I tried doing it the standart way and running        `x instanceof y` always returned false for some reason. 
I have uploaded a short video that visualizes the problem.

[VIDEO](https://www.opentest.co/share/a32aa2e0b4cb11e697503368643fa78e)

Also when I call book.getRecipes() after i tried to push the object r inside book i get [object Object] instead of the value that is contained inside r.

Can provide more info if needed.

Thank you

```
var Recipe = (function() {

  var nextId = 1;

  var constr = function(name, rating, image, category) {

    this._id = nextId++;
    this._name = name || '';
    this._rating = rating || '';
    this._image = image || '';
    this._category = category || '';

    this.setName = function(name) {
      this._name = name;
    };

    this.setRating = function(rating) {
      this._rating = rating;
    };

    this.setImage = function(image) {
      this._image = image;
    };

    this.setCategory = function(category) {
      this._category = category;
    };
  };
  return constr;
})();
```

And

```
var Book = (function() {

  var construct = function(recipes) {

    this._recipes = recipes || [];

    this.addRecipe = function(recipe) {
      this._recipes.push(recipe);
    };

    this.removeRecipe = function(id) {
      this._recipes.splice(id, 1);
    };

    this.getRecipes = function() {
      return this._recipes;
    };
  };
  return construct;
})();
```

And app.js where it is all initialized (loadData function is pre-written(not by me!)):

```
var app = app || {};

(function(recipeBook) {
var book = new Book();
var r = new Recipe();



  $('#add_book').click(function () {

    var $name = $('.uk-form').find('#name').val();
    var $rating = $('.uk-form').find('#rating').val();
    var $image = $('.uk-form').find('#image').val();
    var $category = $('.uk-form').find('#category :selected').val();
    r._name = $name;
    r._rating = $rating;
    r._image = $image;
    r._category = $category;
    book.addRecipe(r);
                        //trying add a recipe into the book

    loadData();

  });

  $("#clear_book").click(function() {
    (".uk-form").reset();
    console.log('clears recipe form');


});


$(document).on('click','.remove',function(ev){
    // still not implemented
    console.log('remove target recipe by Id');
    loadData();
});

loadData();

function loadData() {
    var meat = book.getRecipes().filter(function(r) {
        return r._category === "meat";
    });

    var vegan = book.getRecipes().filter(function(r) {
        return r._category === "vegan";
    });

    var dessert = book.getRecipes().filter(function(r) {
        return r._category === "dessert";
    });

    var source   = $("#recipe-trmplate").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var contextMeat = {meat:meat};
    var contextvegan = {meat:vegan};
    var contextdessert = {meat:dessert};
    var html    = template(contextMeat);
    var html2    = template(contextvegan);
    var html3    = template(contextdessert);

    $('#meat_recipes').html(html);
    $('#vegan_recipes').html(html2);
    $('#dessert_recipes').html(html3);
}

}(app));
```

app.js is mostly pre-written by another person, my job within it is to add the DOM manipulations (add/remove book etc.)

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: You are kinda mixing 'new' logic with functional logic.  Which way are you wanting to go?

Comment: http://collabedit.com/d3ss7

Comment: Uh, that's not a response to the question.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure, wouldn't be asking for help if I was. If I am mixing 'new' logic with functional logic that answers your question pretty much. Still learning and I don't know which way is right

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra } in your click handler.  Probably a typo.  It's confusing that you name your book ctor 'book' and later use the same name for an instance of book.  The book constructor needs to be passed an array to assign to its _recipes property.  You could do

```
`this._recipes = recipes || [];
```

The fiddly stuff aside, I'm not sure what is puzzling you. You would need to get the data out of the HTML, probably using jQuery and statements like

```
`var name = $('input selector string').val()`
 or possibly 
`var rating = $('div selector string').html()'
```

etc ...

and then invoke your recipe constructor with these values

and finally add it to your book   as book.add( newRecipe )

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
<form id="newRecipe">
    <input id="name" type="text"/>
    <input id="rating" type="text"/>
    <input id="file" type="file"/>
    <select id="category" >
        <option>Cat 1</option>
        <option>Cat 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Recipe" />
</form>

<script>
$("#newRecipe").submit(function(){

    var name = $(this).find("#name").val();
    var rating = $(this).find("#rating").val();
    .....
})
</script>
```

On the other hand, I can't really understand the way you are creating your objects. You are implementing auto executing functions.

Seems to me the right way is like:

```
function recipe(name, rating){
    this._name = name;
    this._rating = rating;

    this.setName = function(name) {
       this._name = name;
    };

    //your methods here
}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for the replies.

As to why some things seem confusing - I am quite new to OOP and this is a part of an assignment I have been given.  The app.js is pre-written and my role is to implement the classes 'recipe' and 'book' , add some DOM manipulations and make it all work together. I was totally unfamiliar with classes in JS before this and it is still hard to understand some things.
Will keep trying tho, will get it done eventually. Apologies for the confusion.